# Vuex : compose a state item from several pieces of state

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Suppose my Vuex store has the following members in state:

- numberOfClicks
- productID
- addCartTime
- purchaseTime
- numberOfProducts
- visitProfile

All state members are updated updated via user interaction with the app except the last one, visitProfile, which is a composite formed by merging numberOfClicks, productID, addCartTime and purchaseTime?

Is there a better way than building a plugin for Vuex which will listen for mutations to the composite members and then updating visitProfile?

```
const purchaseProfile = store => {
  store.subscribe((mutation, state) => {

    let _visitP = '';

    if (mutation.type === "numberOfClicks") {
       // update _visitP
     }
    if (mutation.type === "productID") {
       // update _visitP
     }
    if (mutation.type === "addCartTime") {
       // update _visitP
     }
    if (mutation.type === "purchaseTime") {
       // update _visitP
     }

    commit(visitProfile, _visitP);
  })
}

// use plugin 
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  // ...
  plugins: [purchaseProfile]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want `visitProfile` to be a Getter: https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/getters.html